# How to sort taxonomy terms on a term reference field?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy term reference field on a node. On the "node/add" page I would like to sort the terms by "due date" (a field added to that vocabulary).

Comment: Taxonomy terms are entities, could you use the Entity Reference module with a view as the widget? Then you could use a view to order the terms by the custom field

Comment: didn't know ER can do that. Do I need to use http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget?

Comment: You can do if you want a more advanced widget, but if you just need a dropdown you can use the built in views integration. Just create a view with an _Entity Reference_ display, then use the _Views: Filter by entity reference view_ mode when you're configuring the field

Answer (score 5):

If you're stuck using a term reference field, here are some widget options:

- https://drupal.org/project/term_reference_sortable
- https://drupal.org/project/ttr_configurable_widget
- https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_orderselect

Answer (score 0):

I had succsefull manage this by [this module, Views Term Hierarchy Weight Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_term_hierarchy_weight_field), just add (hidden) Hierarchical weight field, then, on sort settings, sort by this new field.